# Erro ao redirecionar usuário em typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou tentando fazer um código para quando o usuário clicar em um botão, ele seje redirecionado para outra página, porém isto não está funcionando, este é o código:

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import 'style.css'
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function useGoTabela() {
 const navigate = useNavigate();

 function goTabela() {
    const url = "/tabela-geral";
    navigate(url);
 }

 return goTabela;
}

const product = undefined 

function Home() {
  const goTabela = useGoTabela();
  const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.ShbKAV5eZf5O9xkago2clgd-nOe9LDSZn57UstbfBjA';
  const getProduto = async (text: string) => {
    console.log(text);
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/informacoes-produtos?query=${text}`, {
      method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      },
    },);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)
  }
  
  return (
    
    <div style={{height: '1000px'}}>  
    <header className="bg-gradient-to-b from-white to-gray-200 text-center shadow-lg h-36" style={{width: '100vw'}}>
      {/* svg here */}
    </header>
  
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="content">
  
    <main className="container mt-4 p-4" style={{height: '10vh'}}>
      <section className="">
        <br />
          {/*Fazer código para ligar com o backend para quando o usuário colocar as informações buscar pelo produtos e mostrar os seus preços em forma de pop-up*/}
        <div className="bg-white p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md w-72 " style={{marginLeft: '28vw', height: '160px', marginTop: '70px'}}>
          <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-2 hover:cursor-default">O que deseja procurar?</h2>
          <ul>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Código' className='w-52 border-b-2 border-orange-500' onChange={({target: {value}}) => getProduto(value)} />
              <button className="mt-4 w-32 bg-orange-600 h-10 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-orange-700 transition duration-600 ease-in-out" style={{boxShadow: 'rgba(234, 88, 12, 0.24) 2  px 5px 10px;'}} onClick={getProduto}>Procurar</button>
          </ul>
        </div>
  
        <div className="bg-white py-4 rounded-lg shadow-md w-64 cursor-default" style={{marginLeft: '46.8vw', marginTop: '-160px', zIndex: '9999', height: '400px', width: '370px'}}>
            <h1 className='text-xl font-semibold text-center' >Produto</h1>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>Linha:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '70px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.linha}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>Código:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '80px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.codigo}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>Franqueado:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '120px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.franqueado}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>Pv-Limite:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '100px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.pvlimite}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>Pv-Agressivo-b:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '145px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.pvagrb}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>Pv-Reposição:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '135px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.pvreposicao}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>Pv-Agressivo-a:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '145px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.pvagra}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>Pv-Sugerido:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '125px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.pvsugerido}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>loc36:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '70px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.loc36}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>loc48:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '70px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.loc48}</h3>
            <h3 className='p-4 -mt-2'>loc60:</h3>
            <h3 className='text-orange-600 font-semibold' style={{marginLeft: '70px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>{product?.loc60}</h3>
            
            <button className="mt-10 ml-4 w-36 bg-orange-600 h-10 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-orange-700 transition duration-600 ease-in-out" style={{boxShadow: 'rgba(234, 88, 12, 0.24) 2  px 5px 10px;'}} >Adicionar Produto</button>
            <button className="mt-10 ml-12 w-36 bg-orange-600 h-10 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-orange-700 transition duration-600 ease-in-out" style={{boxShadow: 'rgba(234, 88, 12, 0.24) 2  px 5px 10px;'}} onClick={goTabela}>Ir para tabela</button>
        </div>
  
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
  <link rel="script" href="index.js" />
  </div>
     
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Não seria mais fácil criar um `<a href="...">`?

Answer (score -4):

Parece que você está utilizando o React com Next.js e React Router para fazer a navegação entre páginas, mas existem alguns pontos no código que podem estar causando problemas no redirecionamento.

O uso do React Router (useNavigate) pode estar conflitando com o Next.js, já que o Next.js geralmente usa sua própria maneira de navegar entre páginas.

Aqui estão algumas sugestões para resolver o problema:

Use o next/router para navegar: Para navegar entre páginas no Next.js, é melhor utilizar o next/router. Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();

  function goTabela() {
    router.push('/tabela-geral');
  }

  // Restante do seu código...

  return (
    // ...Seu código JSX
    <button onClick={goTabela}>Ir para Tabela</button>
    // ...Outros elementos
  );
}
```

Verifique o uso da função getProduto: A função getProduto está sendo chamada tanto no evento de onChange quanto no onClick do botão "Procurar". Certifique-se de que a lógica dentro dessa função está correta para evitar conflitos.

Cheque os imports e dependências: Certifique-se de que todas as dependências estejam corretamente instaladas e importadas no seu projeto.

Após fazer esses ajustes, você deve conseguir redirecionar corretamente para a página desejada. Experimente essas mudanças e veja se o redirecionamento funciona como esperado!

Comment: Você usando GPT? Decepção.